# How do I return a blank instead of #N/A if there is no value in this formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a value in a range and returning the value base on user selected value. The value returns correctly if there is a match but when there is no match, it returns #N/A. How do I return blank or something else other than #N/A?

```
=INDEX(AB4:AB14,MATCH(P26,AA4:AA14,0))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap that in `IfError()`:

`=IfError(INDEX(AB4:AB14,MATCH(P26,AA4:AA14,0)),"")`

Or if you don't have `IfError()`:

`=If(IsErr(INDEX(AB4:AB14,MATCH(P26,AA4:AA14,0)),"",INDEX(AB4:AB14,MATCH(P26,AA4:AA14,0)))`